# Cloudera beeswax server and hive server

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, beeswax

I have a fundamental question regarding the two servers mentioned in the context of cloudera cdh4 distribution

1. Are those two interchangeable/replaceable as in could you run beeswax in place of hive server?
2. I'm trying to use a thrift client to connect and in my set up only the beeswax is running and not the hive server. In such a case can I connect to the beeswax server?

Answer (score 1):

Hive Server is the default process and Beeswax is a newer process designed to better support concurrency and provide authentication using Kerberos. You should run one or the other.

And yes, you should definitely be able to connect to beeswax using Thrift. You can find clients for Beeswax and Hive server [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server).

Comment: Notice that HiveServer2 (next version of Beeswax) is now available and supported in Hue.

Answer (score -1):

what is the difference between hive-server2 and beeswax? They are both designed to better support concurrency and security.

Comment: Ummm... that's not a difference; that something common to both, according to your answer itself.